# Unable to save pdf file from link in Android

Tags: android

I want to download a PDF file from link. I am trying this code.

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "filename.pdf");
long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Also using permission as follows,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But, it giving me "Download Unsuccessful" error

Comment: Can you add log please

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no log is displaying after this event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.....

```
//This method for download file from server by using DownloadManager class
public long downloadAttachment(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtension, String destinationDirectory, String url) {

    DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.
            getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtension);

    return downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
}
```

and call this method.....

```
downloadAttachment(MainActivity.this, filename, "pdf", DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, url);
```

Hope I will help you!